# What is the intuition behind $gt^2/2$ equalling the distance something falls after $t$ seconds?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Let's say $g=10\ \text{m/s}^2$ and it drops for $3$ seconds. For the first second it will drop $10\ \text{m}$, the second it will drop $20\ \text{m}$ ($10 + 10$) and the third second it will drop $30\ \text{m}$. Then if we add $10+20+30$ it equals $60$ but if you use the equation it equals $45$.

Whats the flaw in my thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flaw lies in determining the number of meters the object falls in each second. Take just the first 1-second interval as an example. You stated it would fall 10 meters, while it will actually fall $gt^2/2=5\ \text{m}$.

The basis of the flaw above is in your interpretation for $g$. This quantity tells you how much the *velocity* changes every second, not the distance it falls. (You may want to review your textbook for interpretations of *acceleration*.)

Alright, you asked for the intuition behind $d=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$. To help with that, here is the same equation written in a useful form:

$$d=\frac{0+gt}{2}t$$

The fraction $\frac{0+gt}{2}$ is just the *average speed* throughout the fall. (This works because the speed increases *linearly*, meaning $g$ is constant.) The intuition behind your equation, then, is that **you're multiplying the average speed by the time to get the distance.**

Answer (score 3):

g is telling you the constant rate at which the velocity is changing. So initially the velocity is 0 and after 1 second the velocity is 10 m/s. The average velocity during that first second is 5 m/sec so the mass has fallen 5 m. In the second second the initial velocity is 10 m/s and at the end of that second it is 20 m/s. The average velocity over that second is 15 m/sec and the mass has fallen an additional 15 m. Finally in the third second the initial velocity is 20 m/s, final velocity is 30 m/s,  average is 25 m/s, and thus distance fallen is 25 m. Add the three distances, 5+15+25=45, same as the formula.

Shortcut: Initial velocity is 0, after 3 seconds the final velocity is 30 m/s, so  average velocity over 3 second fall is 15 m/s. Distance fallen is 3 seconds times average velocity = 45 m.

Comment: Thanks that's a very good explanation. what if its velocity increases by the square? how would you calculate distance traveled then?

Comment: Well, if there is a simple way to calculate that the average velocity in that case is 1/3 the final velocity(assuming initial velocity is 0) without using calculus, I don't see how at the moment. See the first integral in Bernhard's answer. That's the general case.

Answer (score 3):

You are not making a fundamental error, and your approach is in principle correct. Basically, what you get, is a discretization error. Basically, what you are doing is evaluating the integral

$$d=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}v(t)dt=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} gt dt.$$

Which you approximated with a Riemann sum (maybe unintentionally?), i.e

$$d=\sum_{i=1}^N g t_i \Delta t.$$

You take $N=3$, $\Delta t=(t_1-t_0)/N=1\text{ s}$ and $t_i=i\Delta t$.

Decrease the time interval $\Delta t$, and eventually you will approach the $45\text{ m}$ you are expecting.

Comment: I like this perspective.